# Can I use a cursor/pointer to navigate an n-ary linked tree with children of multiple types in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, data-structures, casting

I'm working in Swift and I have the following code (bear with me):

```swift
class Node {
    var parent: Node? = nil
    var name: String = ""
    private var _size: Int = 0
    var size: Int { get { return _size } }
    init(name: String, size: Int = 0) {
        self.name = name
        self._size = size
    }
}

class Directory: Node {
    private var _children: [Node] = []
    var children: [Node] {
        get { return _children }
        set(children) {
            _children = children
            for child in _children {
                child.parent = self
            }
        }
    }
    override var size: Int {
        get { return children.map { $0.size }.reduce(0, +) }
    }

    func append(node: Node) {
        _children.append(node)
        node.parent = self
    }

    func remove(name: String) {
        if let i = _children.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == name }) {
            _children[i].parent = nil
            _children.remove(at: i)
        }
    }

    func remove(node: Node) {
        self.remove(name: node.name)
    }

    func findBy(name: String) -> Node? {
        if let i = _children.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == name }) {
            return _children[i]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class File: Node {}
```

So, that models a tree where `Directory: Node` contains an array of `Node`s that can be `File`s or `Directory`s, which works just as expected when building it. Navigating it in a stateful way is a bit trickier.

Normally, in my previous C/C++ life, I'd have a `Directory *pwd` that I'd use to do stuff like `pwd = (Directory *)pwd->findBy("myFancyName")` which is not the prettiest solution but it works fine for my use case, and that would work if "myFancyName" is indeed a `Directory`, which I can pretty much guarantee based on my use case.

So I went on an made a `var pwd: Directory?` but that means I can't do `pwd = pwd.findBy(name: "myFancyname")` because that method returns a `Node?`. So I made `pwd: Node?` but that forces me to go around the place doing `(pwd as! Directory)` all the time I need to call a method from the `Directory` class, which kinda works but is a bit ugly.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: What about making Node a protocol instead?

Comment: I guess I could but then what would be the return type of `findBy`?

Comment: It would be the protocol

Comment: Well, that helped, but it required quite the rewrite. If you wouldn't mind adding this as an answer, I will accept it!